# Print output in a single line in tinyxml

Tags: xml, visual-c++, xml-parsing, tinyxml, tinyxml++

I am using TinyXML to save and print XML documents.

While printing the document I am getting:

```
<document>
   <data>1</data>
   <data>2</data>
   <data>3</data>
</document>
```

as result.

But I want the result to be printed in a single line like this:

```
<document><data>1</data><data>2</data><data>3</data></document>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/) (copied below), I assume you're using `Print` or `Save`, so you get "pretty printed" output

[image]

but as you see from the alternatives above and also from [this documentation](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/doxygen/loon/html/tinyxml_8cpp.html), you can instead use the `<<` operator to output directly to an `ostream`, where the documentation says

> Note that this outputs without any newlines or formatting, as opposed to Print(), which includes tabs and new lines.

So to save to a file, something like this

```
     TiXmlPrinter printer;
     printer.SetStreamPrinting();
     base.Accept( &printer );
     out << printer.Str();
     return out;
```

Comment: The second link you posted is very useful! I updated your answer to include the code from it. Thank you.

Comment: @Derek - thanks, I saw that and approved your edit :-)